# Solving systems of equations for m and b when you know they are both positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am trying to make a website that runs off of this equation. I am only in algebra but I am trying to solve a systems of equation where instead of solving for $x$ and $y$ I am solving for $m$ and $b$. Here is the equation:

$$100,333.333333=m10.3333333+b$$ 
$$6000=(m10.333333+b)-(m5+b)$$

I solved this by solving it the same way you would solve for $x$ and $y$ and I got:

$1125=m$

$-1291.66666666=b$

For the equation to work perfectly it would be best if I could make both $m$ and $b$ positive. Is there any way that I could make it so that the equation is true but both $m$ and $b$ are positive?

Thank you for your response!

Comment: i don't know if this helps but there was a typo.

Comment: If you expected a positive result and didn't get it, then there is something wrong in your model (the equations or the solution). Maybe a coefficient or a sign somewhere. I get $m=1125$ and $b=88700$. I suggest showing how you get your values.

Answer (score 1):

A linear system of equations either has zero solutions, one solution or infinitely many solutions. So no, you can't find another value of $b$.

Comment: even though you can also change the m variable to make a kind of new equation and you have new information about both the variables?

Comment: It's likely you'll simply make the system insolvable.